# Updating a list by changing all its elements

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have these 3 lists.

```
public List<Rectangle> CoTree;
public List<Rectangle> CoRock;
public List<Rectangle> PlayerBlock = new List<Rectangle>();
```

In the update method I want  to change all the elements in both lists(`CoTree` and `CoRock`) and to put both lists in `PlayerBlock` lits so that it will change all the elements in `PlayerBlock`.

```
CoTree=tree.HitBox.FindAll(item => item.Intersects(player.HitBox));
CoRock=rock.HitBox.FindAll(item => item.Intersects(player.HitBox));

// what I need is PlayerBlock = CoTree+CoRock;
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if an item can occur in both `CoTree` and `CoRock`. If it can, you should use [`Union`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.union(v=vs.100).aspx), to get a list in that contains every element only once:

```
PlayerBlock = CoTree.Union(CoRock).ToList();
```

You can use [`Concat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb302894%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) if it is no problem that an element occurs twice in `PlayerBlock`:

```
PlayerBlock = CoTree.Concat(CoRock).ToList();
```

Comment: It is worth nothing that `Union` works only as expected if the class  overrides `Equals`+`GetHashCode` or you provide a `IEqualityComparer<Rectangle>`. But if it is actually `System.Drawing.Rectangle` it already overrides the methods  meaningfully.

Comment: Freudian slip: _"It is worth nothing"_ --> _"It is worth noting"_

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `Concat` method.

You should use `CoTree.Concat(CoRock)` and then `ToList()` to convert to a List